# Filedialog print file path not properly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

l am doing practice with Tkinter and its feature. l have been working on "filedialog". I have no problem with select the file. But, l would like to select an image and open on Tkinter. However, it keep giving error when l click on open the image.
When Printed out the path of file, `io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/GIS/Python_Pro/Tkinter_lib/my_image/nature_1.jpg' mode='r' encoding='cp1254`. How can l get only  path as `'D:/GIS/Python_Pro/Tkinter_lib/my_image/nature_1.jpg'.

```
def Select_File():
    root.filename =filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir='D:\GIS\Python_Pro\Tkinter_lib\my_image',title="Select a file",filetypes=(("png files","*.png"),("ico files","*.ico"),("All Files","*.*")))
    path_file=Label(root,text=root.filename ).pack()
    my_img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
    img_label=Label(root,image=my_img).pack()

#Buttons
Btn_1=Button(root,text="Select a file",command=Select_File).pack()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `filedialog.askopenfile` will return a `IO` object.You can use this   when you need to revise this file.

If you just need to get the full path,use `filedialog.askopenfilename`,and it will return the file path you select.

Answer (score 0):

try filedialog.askopenfilename instead of filedialog.askopenfile